# How to do a dotCloud pull?

Tags: python, git, dotcloud

I have a python app on dotCloud. I publish my original code with `dotCloud push`. After that I login to that app with `dotcloud run --application myApp www.0` and install [something](http://www.etiennethomassen.com/notities/2013-12-23-Local-GDAL-on-Webfaction/) on the server. Now I want to edit again some stuff on my local machine and push it to dotCloud. But if I just do a `dotCloud push` again, then the changes I did on the server are obviously gone. How can I first sync these changes with my local files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dotCloud doesn't provide full version control system like features (though the last few pushes are stored for a quick recovery due to a bad push), so it is not recommended to make changes to a running service because, as you've already mentioned, once you push again the changes you've made are effectively gone from your service image. [In general](http://docs.dotcloud.com/firststeps/platform-overview/#general-workflow), you should work locally, test locally, push, test, then repeat the cycle.

It's not clear what you've installed, so depending on what you've done manually, the approach might vary.

- If you've apt-get installed something, you'll need to add that to your dotCloud.yml using the systempackages directive. See the [build file docs](http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/build-file/#example-dotcloud-yml) for more info.
- If it's code changes you've made, you can ssh into your service using `dotcloud run -A <appname> <servicename>.<instance>` and either copy the files one at a time or tar it up and pull it from your service manually.  There's more information in the [dotCloud copy guide](http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/copy/#download-binary-or-multiple-files) on how to move files from and to a dotcloud service.
- If you've [pip installed a dependency](http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/python/#code-dependencies), you'll need to add these to your requirements.txt file locally and it will be picked up with the next push.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I installed GDAL in a certain way as described [here](http://www.etiennethomassen.com/notities/2013-12-23-Local-GDAL-on-Webfaction/). Unfortunately pip doesn't work with GDAL, so I guess I go with scp.